# How to define the features that bring more variance?

Tags: pca, variance

I have a dataset with 10 column, that are my features, and 1732 row that are my registrations. This registration are divided in 15 classes, so I have several registration for every class in my dataset. My goal is to define what is the most important feature, the one that brings more variance between classes.

I'm trying to use PCA, but because of the several registration for every classes it's difficult to find the right way of use oof this method.

Is there another method that can I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any direct method for your problem. But i suggest to use Forward Selection idea for it. I mean you can classify based on each column of your table. Then see which feature gives you best accuracy. The column with the most accuracy rate is your most important feature to your classify problem.

Comment: I don't think that I can use a regression because in my dataset some features are qualitative (for example black/white, cat/dog/fish and so on)

Comment: If you have enough data, you can do regression on each of the features and conclude the best feature on the results. for example you can do a regression on cat class and find the most features. then do it again for dog and ... . at the end sort the features and conclude the final result on that.